Using a different emulator than Android Emulator ( Android Studio ) for React Native
I'm learning React Native for mobile development and i want to use a different emulator because of my PC can't run Android Emulator ( Android Studio ) smoothly, but i can't find any document about how to use these emulators with React Native. Is there any ways to do this? Any suggestion is appreciated

You can use BlueStacks emulator. it runs smoothly on less specifications Systems
